# How can I modify the List in a Master/Detail template to include thumbnails?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, fragment, master-detail

I have an application that was created with the Master/Detail Flow template in Eclipse:

[image: Master Detail Flow]

I'm interested in modifying the layout to include a thumbnail for each list item in the ListView. Currently, it's populating the listview and I can view each item and the video associated with it, but I can't figure out to add a thumbnail to each item in the listview (each item is an object with properties, one of them being the path to the thumbnail file). I'm new to fragments, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Master Detail Flow with ListView image]

Edit: I'm looking at the ArrayAdapter now in the ListFragment.java and I think I understand how it works.